# Sort an alphanum column in MYSQL query?

Tags: sql, mysql

I would like to display my table rows in this order with an order by :

```
50ACT-1
50ACT-1A1
50ACT-1A5
50ACT-1A10
50ACT-2
```

Except that currently, with my query, my lines are displayed in this order:

```
50ACT-1
50ACT-1A1
50ACT-1A10
50ACT-1A5
50ACT-2
```

There are several posts on the forum on this subject but I haven't found my answer...
Do you have any ideas on what I could put in the order by?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What data is possible in this column? I assume you just showed a small part of your table. What cases need to be covered?

Comment: For your given sample data, something like `ORDER BY LEFT(col,7), LENGTH(col), col` would do, but I doubt this will cover all possible cases.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
Your ORDER BY solved all the problems! Have a nice day!

Comment: @TheoB Note the request for further detail on possible values. With the suggested ordering, `50ACT-1B2` would be between `50ACT-1A5` and `50ACT-1A10`.

Comment: Are values like `6ACT-123B12` and `100ACT-15A8` possible?

Comment: This is like you want to sort number as 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 9, 8 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.

Answer (score 0):

A thorough ordering process can utilize [`regexp_substr`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr) to find the two target digit components of each string, which can then be `cast` as integers in the `order by` clause:

```
select t.s from tbl t order by 
   cast(regexp_substr(t.s, '^\d+') as float), -- first, by leading number
   cast(regexp_substr(t.s, '(?<=\-)\d+') as float), -- then, by number just after the dash
   cast(regexp_substr(t.s, '\d+$') as float) -- lastly, by trailing number (if it exists)
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aCj7mB2Z)